# Dynamically populating List View from Website XML data Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, networking

In my home screen (Main Activity) I have a List View, named `lv`.

I have a separate method, created in MainActivity.java which returns an List of Strings which derived from parsed XML data. See below:

```
public static List<String> getLocs(){

    List<String> sts = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new URL("http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getAllStationsXML_WithStationType?StationType=D").openStream());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList stationames = doc.getElementsByTagName("objStation");

        for(int i = 0; i<stationames.getLength(); i++){

            Element firstStat = (Element) stationames.item(i);
            Element stationalias = (Element) firstStat.getElementsByTagName("StationDesc").item(0);

            sts.add(stationalias.getTextContent().trim());

        }



    } catch (SAXParseException err) {

        System.out.println("** Parsing error" + ", line "
                + err.getLineNumber() + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());

    } catch (SAXException e) {

        Exception x = e.getException();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();

    }

    return sts;

}
```

I have the following method which Toasts whether I have connection or not:

```
public void checkConnection(View view) {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YAY! Connected !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uh oh... problems connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This method is called when a button in the Main Activity is clicked. The important thing is it runs succesfully toasting, "YAY! Connected !". So there is indeed connection.

My Main Activity class contains the following variables and the following onCreate() method, excluding the checkConnection Button which I mentioned above.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView lv;
List<String> stnames  = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    stnames = getLocs();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            stnames );

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

As you can see this is where I am trying to populate the List View using the returned List from the getLoc() method as a parameter for the Adapter for the List View.

However, on debugging, it turns out the `stnames` List is empty, hence the `getLoc()` method failed to work, although it worked perfectly on it's own in Eclipse.

So I figured it has something to do with Android.

It was mentioned to me that I may have to do any internet connections in a different class.

Does this class have to extend ASync? I thought this was just for concurrent threading? This should probably answer my connection about the dynamic list populating.

But should my program still work without declaring a separate class extending ASync?

If so, why is my List View not being populated?

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT**

I have added the following method to my MainActivity class and declared `arrayAdapter` globally for the class also..:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        stnames = getLocs();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                stnames );

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Still no luck though

Comment: Try put the method getLocs() in a subclass of your activity, and make that subclass extend async task. I guess you're having a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to run your network request in a separate thread like an AsyncTask, like @Jones said, try to create a class extending AsyncTask and then in doInBackground() put your getLocs() method. Don't forget to add the INTERNET permission to your Manifest.

Comment: what String value do I return in the overriden `doInBackground()` method. Can I just return a random String, and run my `getLoc()` method inside.

Comment: And will the `doInBackground()` method call automatically on startup of app, or need I run some oher commands in Main Activity or `onCreate()` method?

Comment: fixed it, forgot to execute